# Duplicating tables in Lua

Tags: lua, reference

I'm having trouble with how Lua uses references to duplicate tables. If I have the following code:

```
table = {}
table.hello = "Hello"

function MyFunction (myTable)
        myTable.goodbye = "goodbye"
        return myTable
end

table2 = MyFunction(table)
```

In this code, table2 and table would end up having the exact same content. How could I make it so only table2 had the goodbye variable?

Comment: "Lua uses references to duplicate tables": As I think you understand a Lua variable references a value and an assignment, return or parameter duplicates the reference, not the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a new table and copy all the fields from the old one into it:

```
function MyFunction (oldTable)
    local newTable = {}
    for k,v in pairs(oldTable) do
        newTable[k] = v
    end
    newTable.goodbye = "goodbye"
    return newTable
end
```

The example, I gave only does a shallow copy so if oldTable has fields that are also mutable tables then they will only be copied by reference. For more information, see http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable

Answer (score 3):

You literally have to copy the table.

If it's an array, so contains only numbers as key, the you can use a classic loop:

```
for i=1, #table do
    table2[i] = table[i]
end
```

But if you use text references, like in your example with `table.goodbye`, you need to iterate by key-value pairs:

```
for k,v in pairs(table) do
    table2[k] = v
end
```

In both loops, `table` means the table *from* which you want to copy, and `table2`is the one *to* which you paste.

Comment: Note: pairs iterates over every key, not just those that are of type string.

Comment: Also note: `for i=1, #table do` iterates over positive integers from 1 to the "length" of the table, which is well-defined only when the [table has a sequence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) (perhaps that's a superset of what you mean by "is an array"; perhaps not, because to me an array simply means a bounded range of integer keys with any value, but a sequence cannot include nil values).

Comment: @TomBlodget I had no intention to imply; instead, I tried to focus on that simple for does *not* iterate on the *non*-integer keys. The second comment, on the other hand is new even for me, thanks for enlightening!